# The problem of matching data between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### The first dataframe(df1) is similar to this:

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A |
| 2022-01-02 | A |
| 2022-01-03 | A |
| 2022-01-01 | B |
| 2022-01-02 | B |
| 2022-01-03 | B |

### The column name of the second dataframe (df2) is the date of df1, and the row name is the 'Name' data of df1, which is similar to this:

| Result | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-31 | False | True | True |
| 2022-01-01 | False | False | True |
| 2022-01-02 | False | True | False |
| 2022-01-03 | True | False | True |

### I want to extract the data of df2 to df1 and generate a new column of data with the same dates and names:
Get a result similar to the following:

| Date | Name | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | False |
| 2022-01-02 | A | False |
| 2022-01-03 | A | True |
| 2022-01-01 | B | False |
| 2022-01-02 | B | True |
| 2022-01-03 | B | False |

### I tried to use for loop to get the date and name of df1, and then extract the data of df2, but because of the large amount of data, there are many files that need to be merged, it takes a lot of time. Besides, the updates are frequent, so I would like to ask, is there any more efficient Methods?
Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not clear to me how you want to extract the data of df2. That is how are you matching? For your description I would expect the "result" column in your example to be [True, False, True, False, ...]. You have a good sense to suspect something is wrong. As a general guide if you're using for loops with a pandas DataFrame you're doing something wrong or at least not taking advantage of the package.

Comment: You must provide a reproducible input, not images

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Comment: I have convert images to tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape df2 (from wide to long) by using [pd.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). I made a small change to a column name in df2 to simplify the solution.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03"],
        "Name": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"]
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["2021-12-31", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03"],
        "A": [False, False, False, True],
        "B": [True, False, True, False],
        "C": [True, True, False, True],
    }
)
df2_long = df2.melt(
    id_vars=['Date'],
    value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C'],
    var_name="Name",
    value_name="Result"
)
result = df1.merge(df2_long, on=['Date', 'Name'])
```

Comment: Realizing that the issue was with the shape of the data, you should consider renaming your question.